# Rotation matrix not returning correct number on the Z Axis

Tags: java, math, vector

I made a method in my Java code which translates a 3 coordinate vector into another 3 coordinate system basing my method on the [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations) which OpenGL used to have, here is the full method:

```java
public static float[] rotateVector3 (float x, float y, float z, double rX, double rY, double rZ){

        float[] ret = {x,y,z};
        while(rX < 0){rX += Math.PI*2;}
        while(rY < 0){rY += Math.PI*2;}
        while(rZ < 0){rZ += Math.PI*2;}
        while(rX >= Math.PI*2){rX -= Math.PI*2;}
        while(rY >= Math.PI*2){rY -= Math.PI*2;}
        while(rZ >= Math.PI*2){rZ -= Math.PI*2;}

        //ret[0] *= 1;
        ret[1] *= Math.cos(rX) - Math.sin(rX);
        ret[2] *= Math.sin(rX) + Math.cos(rX);

        ret[0] *= Math.cos(rY) + Math.sin(rY);
        //ret[1] *= 1;
        ret[2] *= - Math.sin(rY) + Math.cos(rY);

        ret[0] *= Math.cos(rZ) - Math.sin(rZ);
        ret[1] *= Math.sin(rZ) + Math.cos(rZ);
        //ret[2] *= 1;

        System.out.println("(" + x + " " + y + " " + z +") -> (" + rX + "º " + rY + "º " + rZ + "º) = (" + ret[0] + " " + ret[1] + " " + ret[2] + ")");
        return ret;

    }
```

However this method for some reason does not work well with the Z axis.

Let's assume for instance that i have 4 arrays representing vectors, each with 3 coordinates (XYZ respectively):
`vecA = {50,50,1}, vecB = {50,-50,1}, vecC = {-50f,-50f,1}, vecD = {-50f,50f,1}`

When I input those values in their respective order in the method, with each value of the rotation being {0,2,0} radians respectively, I get the following output:

```
(50.0 50.0 1.0) -> (0.0º 2.0º 0.0º) = (24.65753 50.0 -1.3254442)
(50.0 -50.0 1.0) -> (0.0º 2.0º 0.0º) = (24.65753 -50.0 -1.3254442)
(-50.0 -50.0 1.0) -> (0.0º 2.0º 0.0º) = (-24.65753 -50.0 -1.3254442)
(-50.0 50.0 1.0) -> (0.0º 2.0º 0.0º) = (-24.65753 50.0 -1.3254442)
```

Which does not make sense. As I am rotating in the Y axis, the vectors with the Y coordinates above zero should be farther that those with the negative Y coordinates, yet it always returns the same Z values regardless and I'm not entirely sure why, is there any correction that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the correct way to do this is

```java
public static float[] rotateVector3 (float x, float y, float z, double rX, double rY, double rZ, float aX, float aY, float aZ){

        float[] ret = new float[3];
        while(rX < 0){rX += Math.PI*2;}
        while(rY < 0){rY += Math.PI*2;}
        while(rZ < 0){rZ += Math.PI*2;}
        while(rX >= Math.PI*2){rX -= Math.PI*2;}
        while(rY >= Math.PI*2){rY -= Math.PI*2;}
        while(rZ >= Math.PI*2){rZ -= Math.PI*2;}

        double cosX = Math.cos(rX);
        double cosY = Math.cos(rY);
        double cosZ = Math.cos(rZ);
        double sinX = Math.sin(rX);
        double sinY = Math.sin(rY);
        double sinZ = Math.sin(rZ);

        double Axx = cosX*cosY;
        double Axy = cosX*sinY*sinZ - sinX*cosZ;
        double Axz = cosX*sinY*cosZ + sinX*sinZ;

        double Ayx = sinX*cosY;
        double Ayy = sinX*sinY*sinZ + cosX*cosZ;
        double Ayz = sinX*sinY*cosZ - cosX*sinZ;

        double Azx = -sinY;
        double Azy = cosY*sinZ;
        double Azz = cosY*cosZ;

        x-=aX;
        y-=aY;
        z-=aZ;

        ret[0] = (float) (Axx*x + Axy*y + Axz*z);
        ret[1] = (float) (Ayx*x + Ayy*y + Ayz*z);
        ret[2] = (float) (Azx*x + Azy*y + Azz*z);


        System.out.println("(" + x + " " + y + " " + z +") -> (" + rX + "º " + rY + "º " + rZ + "º) = (" + ret[0] + " " + ret[1] + " " + ret[2] + ")");
        return ret;

    }
```

I'd explain how this works but that would imply that I actually know what I'm doing